# Invoke OCaml compiler to just produce .cmi

Tags: header, ocaml, compilation

maybe I'm just failing in a really simple thing but I'm developing an intepreter written in OCaml with standard tools as **ocamllex** and **ocamlyacc** and I have this situation:

- iparser.mly contains parser spec
- ilexer.mll contains lexer spec
- impossible.ml contains the vm that executes the code and all the types needed

The instruction type that defines various instructions is in `impossible.ml` and it is needed by the parser but `impossible.ml` uses the parser defined in `iparser.mly` so they both need each other to compile correctly.

Is there a way to produce just the `.cmi` file for my `impossible.ml`? In this way the parser would know about types defined in `impossible.ml` and it will allow me to compile `impossible.cmo/.cmi` and later compile also `impossible.cmo`. Then I can link all of them together.

So far my compiling script is:

```
ocamlyacc iparser.mly
ocamlc -c iparser.mli
ocamllex ilexer.mll
ocamlc -c ilexer.ml
ocamlc -c iparser.ml
ocamlc -c impossible.ml
ocamlc -o imp.exe ilexer.cmo iparser.cmo impossible.cmo
```

but this doesn't work because `ocamlc -c iparser.ml` needs at least `impossible.cmi` to know the types.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an impossible.mli and compile that.  That will produce the impossible.cmi and only the .cmi.

Alternatively:

```
ocamlc -i impossible.ml
```

will print the mli to stdout.  You could do something like this:

```
ocamlc -i impossible.ml > impossible.mli
ocamlc -c impossible.mli
```

Comment: Can't I just build the normal inferred .cmi? From what I understood using just a .ml file will generate a standard .mli file that publishes everything of the module.. am I right?

Comment: Yeah, you are correct.  I'm just not sure if there is a way to output just the mli/cmi without also compiling the cmo file.  The closest I can find at the moment is ocamlc -i impossible.ml which will print the default mli to stdout.  You could add something to the build process to do that, redirect the output to a file and then compile that.

Comment: I tried to figure it out but ofcourse calling `ocamlc -i impossible.ml` returns in __Error: Unbound value Iparser.first__ because of the same problem exposed in my question. At this point I don't think there are way around writing my own .mli file

Comment: Too bad.  It makes sense though, the default mli makes pretty much everything public.  Your mli can only contain interfaces that don't reference the parser code.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you cannot legitimately compile recursively-dependant modules this way. Either factor out the interdependencies in the third module (usually easy), or pass them as parameters (or mutable initialization references - ugly), or use recursive modules.